# Why can't we have this() and super() together in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

I have this program:

```
public class A
{
    public A(){
    System.out.println("I am in A");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
    B a = new B("Test");
    }
}

class B extends A
{   
    public B(){
    System.out.println("I am in B");
    }

    public B(String s){
    this();
    super();
    System.out.println("I am in B as " + s);
    }
}
```

Now why can't I call the `this` constructor of `B` to invoke the default constructor? This is giving me compile time error.

Comment: normally the super()-call should give you an error. A constructor has to be the first statement in a constructor ;)

Comment: The super() only gives error if the super class does not have a default constructor or a constructor with not argument list

Answer (score 4):

`this` and `super` must be the **first** line in a constructor.

EDITED:

Language spec

> > 8.8.7. Constructor Body
>
> The first statement of a constructor body may be an explicit
>   invocation of another constructor of the same class or of the direct
>   superclass (§8.8.7.1).

Comment: Can you specify what are you saying, means either this(); or super(); can be on first line not both on first line, Are you saying like this "this() super();"

Comment: One of these two statements can be first line, try to re-read quote from specification that I've added to my answer.

Comment: Ya i know only one but why not both when they don't much affect the execution

Comment: If you develop some product you will have some specefication and limitations,  so, you cannot use these two stamenets like you want, because it was described in specification!

Answer (score 1):

`this()` calls another constructor in the same class.

`super()` calls a super constructor.If no `super()` is explicitly written,the compiler will add one implicitly. Hence, you will end up calling `super()` twice.

So, both are not allowed.

---

EDIT

In context of your code : remember, `super()` should always be the first line in a constructor.

Comment: 1. this() can also be the first line
2. You wont end up calling super() twice if we have already mentioned it explicitly

Comment: if both `this()` and `super()` are there, then super has to be the first line. I have specifically written - **in context of your code** for the very same reason. And where did I say that `super()` is called twice if we mention it explicitly?

Comment: If super is the first line then it doesnt compile says this() should be the first line and you worte "Hence, you will end up calling super() twice."

Comment: Logically mate. There is a reason people upvoted the answer.

Comment: If all thought the same way then no one would have any doubts in life dude...
:)

Answer (score 1):

Upon further reflection my answer as it was below  is basically correct but lacking some nuance. Essentially, you can call a super constructor once. This is to ensure your super class is only constructed once. This means that the first line of a given constructor can be a call to another constructor in the current class or a call to a constructor in the super class.  This also means that you can only call another constructor once in any given constructor; you must choose to call one in the current or super class. This ensures that all super classes will be fully constructed before the current object is.

Old explanation:

The fundamental reason is that all super classes must be constructed before the subclass can be. To this end, Java will implicitly call super() if no such invocation exist on the first line of a constructor. The only way to override this behavior is to explicitly call a different constructor in your super class. Basically, Java must create your hierarchy before you can be created.

Putting your constructor first violates this requirement and therefore is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

According to Java this() and super() should be the first statement in constructor.Now the point is we can not write both at once as a first line.If u write this() and not super,dont expect that super will be called implicitly.
It is as simple as it is.U have no option to write them together in single constructor body